# Don´t get a graph in GraphView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-graphview

I implemented the GraphView in my Android Studio Code but I dont get the graph to show in my app. If I press the read button nothing happens. So what do I have to do ?
Thanks for your time and your answers I appreciate it.

```
package yourhome;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.Viewport;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPoint;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.LineGraphSeries;


import java.util.Random;

import yourhome.datasource.ActivityDataSource;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;

public class Hauptfenster extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private String mActivityTitle;

    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
    private LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series;
    private int lastX = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hauptfenster);

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

        addDrawerItems();
        setupDrawer();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        //GraphView initialiesieren
        GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
        //Daten
        series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();
        graph.addSeries(series);
        //Options

        Viewport viewport = graph.getViewport();
        viewport.setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
        viewport.setMinY(1);
        viewport.setMaxY(30);
        viewport.setScrollable(true);


        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        Button lesenBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lesenBtn);
        lesenBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new ActivityDataSource(textView).execute("someParams");


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            addEntry();
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(600);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void addEntry() {
        series.appendData(new DataPoint(lastX++, RANDOM.nextDouble() * 10d), true, 10);
    }



    private void addDrawerItems() {
        String[] osArray = { "Kamera", "LED", "Steckdosen" };
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(Hauptfenster.this, "Coming Soon!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupDrawer() {
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Was möchten sie einsehen ?");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_hauptfenster, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) { return true;}
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();
```

contains no data.
You need something like:

```
series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(values);
```

where the values may be an array of integer values.